# "Зависает" окно QProgressDialog при взаимодействии с запущенным вторичным потоком

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

`QProgressDialog` используется для отображения результатов объёмного расчёта, запущенного в отдельном потоке. Причём объект `QProgressDialog` создаётся в основном потоке приложения

```
// Создаём окно диалога для отображения состояния расчёта
QProgressDialog *progressDialog = new QProgressDialog("Выполняется расчёт...", "&Отмена", 0, 10, mainWindow, Qt::WindowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
progressDialog->setWindowTitle("Подождите");
progressDialog->setAutoReset(false);
progressDialog->setMinimumDuration(0);
progressDialog->show();
connect(progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(cancel_work()) );

// Создаём нить кода для расчёта
ThreadSetExactData *threadSetExactData = new ThreadSetExactData(..., progressDialog);
connect(threadSetExactData, SIGNAL(finished()), threadSetExactData, SLOT(work_done()));
connect(threadSetExactData, SIGNAL(finished()), threadSetExactData, SLOT(deleteLater()));
threadSetExactData->start();
threadSetExactData->setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);
```

Поток взаимодействует с диалогом с помощью механизма сигналов и слотов

```
class ThreadSetExactData : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ThreadSetExactData(..., QProgressDialog *_progressDialog, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~ThreadSetExactData();
protected:
    void run() override;

private slots:
    void work_done();

private:
    QProgressDialog *progressDialog;

signals:
    void set_progress_maximum(int maximum);
    void set_progress_value(int value);
};

ThreadSetExactData::ThreadSetExactData(..., QProgressDialog *_progressDialog, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent), progressDialog(_progressDialog)
{
    ...
    connect(this, SIGNAL(set_progress_maximum(int)), progressDialog, SLOT(setMaximum(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(set_progress_value(int)), progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int)));
}

void ThreadSetExactData::run()
{
    TotalWork = work();
    emit set_progress_maximum(TotalWork);

    ...
    
    while(have_something_to_do())
    {
        ...
        CurrentWork = current_iteration_work();
        emit set_progress_value(CurrentWork);
    }
}
```

Взаимодействие работает нормально (сигналы потока эмитируются и обрабатываются), но только окно диалога не воспринимает действие пользователя, в частности, нажатие на кнопку `Cancel`. Окно вообще не воспринимает события, кнопка `Cancel` "зависает", и, следовательно, никак не эмитирует сигнал `canceled()`. Что довольно странно, т.к. диалог запущен в основном потоке и как будто на нём должен действовать цикл обработки событий основного приложения.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы когда вопрос задаете старайтесь поставить себя на место того, кто его будет читать, осмысливать и отвечать (то есть понять суть чужих-ваших затруднений). Ну зависает ваше диалоговое окно, ну поток, и где этот поток, и какое у него тело, что оно там делает, и как он сигнализирует о своем состоянии в диалог прогресса? По тому коду, что вы предоставили все вроде бы нормально, поэтому надо больше информации и она должна быть ключевой для понимания вашей проблемы. Поэтому вам минус и воткнули (не я :) )

Comment: Большое спасибо за замечание. Вопрос исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не надо передавать указатель на диалог в поток. Эти две сущности (окно и поток), и в целом (по-сути ООП и всех хороших практик проектирования приложений) должны быть слабовязанными, то есть общение должно происходить при помощи публичного интерфейса и, кроме того, как принято в Qt, технологии сигнал-слот (что, поверьте, в ваших же интересах для последующих перепроектирований и улучшений кода).

Во-вторых, мне не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Код ниже, представлен в качестве примера (ваш код тоже нормально работает, исходя из того, как я его понял).

Поток:

```
class Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Thread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void run() {
        int i = 0, max = 100;
        emit set_progress_maximum(max);

        while(i++ < max) {
            emit set_progress_value(i);
            QThread::msleep(500);
        }
    }

signals:
    void set_progress_maximum(int value);
    void set_progress_value(int value);
};
```

Главное окно, слот нажатия на кнопку, запуск потока, отображение окна прогресса (все работает как и ожидается, ничего не зависает):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProgressDialog* dialog = new QProgressDialog();
    Thread* th = new Thread();
    connect(th, &Thread::set_progress_maximum, dialog, &QProgressDialog::setMaximum);
    connect(th, &Thread::set_progress_value, dialog, &QProgressDialog::setValue);

    connect(dialog, &QProgressDialog::canceled, this, [&]() {
        qDebug() << "stop";
    });

    th->start();
    dialog->show();
}
```

Window 11 Qt 6.5.1 MinGW x64

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Такой вопрос: если не передавать progressDialog в поток, то к чему (какому виджету) будет привязываться окно MessageBox для сообщений в потоке (nullptr в качестве parent, думаю, предлагать не стоит).

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению, проблему решить не удалось. В отладчике проверено, что сигнал `QProgressDialog::canceled` попадает на слот для обработки (как указано в коде ответа, `{qDebug() << "stop";}`) лишь после завершения потока, когда в нём уже нет надобности. К тому же, эмиссия этого сигнала вызывается принудительным закрытием окна диалога `close()`, а не нажатием на кнопку `cancel`.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что у вас не работает. Просто создайте пустой проект и сделайте в нём всё то, что я указал вам с своём ответе. Всё должно работать как ожидается. Nullptr можно передать в качестве родителя, но тогда надо не забыть удалить объект при закрытии диалога (это не сложно).

Comment: У меня все нормально работает и в том случае, если передать указатель на MainWindow в конструктор диалога. Все работает и не зависает. Просто поэкспериментируйте в пустом проекте

Comment: Да, естественно, так и сделал: в качестве родителя передал указатель на MainWindow. Более того, я сам сформировал диалог, и связал сигнал clicked() кнопки QPushButton "Отмена" с соответствующим слотом. Результат тот же. Окно диалога ведёт себя как-то странно: реагирует на события перемещения за заголовок, но кнопка не реагирует на события. По идее, при наведении мыши на кнопку должна измениться подсветка, но ничего такого не происходит, и, соответственно, не происходит нажатия. Хотя сигналы изменения состояния прогресса вполне себе работают...